# Assigning text to variables in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, char

I did some searching on here, and I have not found a solution to what I'm looking for. If it's out there, I apologize in advance. I'm a Colorado Technical University student, taking an introductory C++, with zero programming experience previously in C++.

I'm trying to build a program where it is supposed to display text. Visual Studio keeps kicking it back with a build error. After looking at the build notes, I've determined the error is with attempting to assign text a variable. Here is what I have so far:

```
char my_name;
char my_major;
int my_zip;
char my_address;
char my_phone;
char my_city_state;

cin >> "What is your name? " >> my_name;
cin >> "What is your street address, without city, state & ZIP? " >> my_street;
cin >> "What is the City and state that you live in? " >> my_city_state;
cin >> "What is the ZIP code? " >> my_zip;
cin >> "What is your phone number? " >> my_phone;
cin >> "What is your major? " >> my_major;
```

I had tried to direct assign, like this:

```
my_name="C++ User";
```

But in looking at other FAQs here, I realized this is not possible.

How would I be able to either direct assign, as I was initially looking to do, or allow for the input to be assigned?

Note: Basic code lines were taken from RAPTOR output, and I have been able to get it to work with that, just not here with Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance for the help, and again, I'm sorry if there is an answer, but after 15 minutes of looking, I have not been able to find it here.

Comment: Buy a book, man. This stuff would be covered even in the really bad books.

Comment: Look up `std::string`.

Comment: [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) ([tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html))

Comment: I'm a poor college student - not going to pay for a book that I'm only going to be using for a month or two, I'm sorry. Just looking for a quick reply, since the book with the course seems to not have the answer, user 93353.

Comment: Synxis - thank you for that tutorial link - that, along with the two answers below, helped out alot - got it fixed and finally working!  Thank you everyone!

Comment: Have a look at the C++ section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/392926/1227469) for a list of free C++ books/resources.

Comment: @MikeBrinkley find tutorials, free/open textbooks, etc.  If you can't or won't buy a textbook you'll have to be more savvy to learn basic facts.  SO is not a great way to learn these things.

Comment: @MikeBrinkley: You should not edit the title of the question to mark it as "resolved'. Just mark any of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

`my_name` is a single `char`, while what you are trying to assign to it is a string literal (i.e. an *array* of `char`s).

I would suggest using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) here. For instance:

```
#include <string> // Header required for std::string

// ...

std::string my_name = "C++ User";
```

Besides, you should't be using `operator >>` with a string literal on the right hand side. Instead of doing this:

```
cin >> "What is your name? " >> my_name;
```

You should be doing this:

```
std::cout << "What is your name? "; // Print a message to the standard output
std::cin >> my_name; // Read a string from the standard input
```

Comment: Thank you, Andy, this helped me with the solution to my errors!

Comment: Perhaps add something about his incorrect use of `cin` to make the answer complete?

Comment: @JBentley: I somehow overlooked that. Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

You should use std::string to get string input from user,std::cout to display user message and std::cin to get user input.

Something like this you will also need #include

```
std::string name;

std::cout<<"What is your name "<<std::endl;
std::cin >> name;
```